# Create date slider for leaflet map in R

Tags: r, r-leaflet

At the moment I've got some ERA5 precipitation data as a `RasterStack` from which I take a `RasterLayer` and plot that. To create a simple plot at the moment I've got:

```
  precipitation_data <- raster::stack(era5_precip_filepath)
  precipitation_data <- raster::projectRaster(precipitation_data, crs = "+proj=utm +zone=32")

  selected_month <- precipitation_data$X2021.10.01

  leaflet::leaflet() %>% 
  leaflet::addTiles() %>%
  leaflet::addRasterImage(x = selected_month, opacity = 1)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is select a `RasterLayer` to plot from the stack using a date slider. Dates are easily found from the name of each layer:

```
> names(era5_precip)
 [1] "X2021.10.01" "X2021.10.02" "X2021.10.03" "X2021.10.04" "X2021.10.05" "X2021.10.06" "X2021.10.07" "X2021.10.08" "X2021.10.09" "X2021.10.10" "X2021.10.11" "X2021.10.12" "X2021.10.13" "X2021.10.14" "X2021.10.15" "X2021.10.16"
[17] "X2021.10.17" "X2021.10.18" "X2021.10.19" "X2021.10.20" "X2021.10.21" "X2021.10.22" "X2021.10.23" "X2021.10.24" "X2021.10.25" "X2021.10.26" "X2021.10.27" "X2021.10.28" "X2021.10.29" "X2021.10.30" "X2021.10.31"
```

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to do this?

Comment: leaflet.extras2::addTimeslider

Comment: `leaflet.extras2::addTimeslider`, according to the docs, is only for "Simple Feature collection of type POINT or LINESTRING with a column of class Date or POSIXct." How can it be used with raster data?

Comment: I ended up doing this inside a Shiny app instead and used a slider there to select from the stack of rasters. I'll try and get a simplified version of the app I created up soon,